chain is skipping on cog. What's wrong?
Here are two video which is shoot by my high speed camera.
Video 1
Video 2
My chain is brand new now.
What's wrong here?  Is it rear derailleur or cog?

Dear fellow rider. It is impossible to tell from this video. Worn cogs, poorly adjusted deraileur and bent hanger are all common causes. If it slips on only 1-3 cogs, it's most likely worn cogs. If only 1-2 don't slip, it may be a bent hanger. If every cog causes slippage, severe wear/(mismatch with new chain) or a maladjusted deraileur can be suspected. Since you had to replace the chain, wear is a first suspect. If the shifts are good, deraileur/hanger is probably ok. Good luck!

@WornChain that's an answer.  Please post as an answer.

I believe you are experiencing what happens when a new chain is used on a worn drivetrain.  A drivetrain that has been worn abnormally by a stretched/elongated chain.  Especially in video one, I see no attempts by the chain to climb or descend from it's cog on the cassette which might indicate the derailleur indexing was off.  Essentially it appears that the chain suddenly slips forward before regaining some purchase on the cog.  That is exactly the symptom of a new chain on an abnormally worn cassette or chainring.
The remedy is to replace the worn cassette cog with new. And then to check your chain and replace it when it becomes elongated by 0.75%.  Typically, cassettes can last for 3 lifetimes of chains if the chains are changed when 0.75% wear or less.  One could also put the old chain back on or try a worn chain on the current drivetrain.  The old or worn chain's longer pitch will better match the abnormal wear of the cassette.
Here is an article on chain and sprocket wear written by the great Sheldon Brown.  It details the reasons behind what you are experiencing with your new chain on the old drivetrain.
